# Como mandar dados salvos de um formulário em Android para o email?

Tags: android

Em vez de salvar no `sqlite`, gostaria de mandar p/ meu `email`. Alguém sabe como fazer?

Comment: Esta questão foi respondida no seguinte link. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2020088/sending-email-in-android-using-javamail-api-without-using-the-default-built-in-a

Comment: obrigado, era isso mesmo que eu queria...